# how to clear pointer variable which is holding start of memory location that needs to be cleared for 20 bytes of data from starting location

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

Pointer variable is holding the value which is nothing but an address of memory location that needs to be cleared for next 20 bytes of data.

I have tried below code snippet but it clears the value of pointer value (address of starting memory location). By doing so, i lost the start address of memory location (pointer value).

```
srcadr = 0x105fc080;

i = 20;

*srcptr = &srcadr

if(srcptr != NULL)
{

    while (i < 20)

   {
        *srcptr++ = 0x00;
   }

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. `*srcptr = &srcadr` sets the pointer to point at the address of `srcadr`, not to point at the absolute address `0x105fc080`. Furthermore, nobody can answer this question without seeing the variable declarations.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with embedded systems, smart pointers and void pointers?

Comment: Is there a strong smell of an XY-problem in the air?

Comment: Also, to begin with this code is incorrect for updating raw memory locations, since you don't use the `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: Besides the other mentioned problems... What about just making a copy before you start modifying your pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete.

But let's assume this first line is valid:

```
srcadr = 0x105fc080;
```

that means `srcadr` can be an unsigned int (or unsigned long).

Then we need to treat that as a pointer, and clear 20 bytes from that address:

```
volatile unsigned char * const area = (unsigned char *) srcadr;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  area[i] = 0;
```

The cast is necessary in order to treat the address value as a pointer. Using `&srcadr` makes no sense at all, that gives us the address of the `srcadr` pointer variable, which is irrelevant.

Note for future readers: if you can, of course you'd just use `memset()`this like so:

```
memset((void *) 0x105fc080, 0, 20);
```

and be done. But the OP can't use that for whatever reason, perhaps it's an embedded environment with a limited standard library (and, uh, dull compiler without an intrinsic) for instance.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is set 20 Byte of memory to 0 you can use memset.
All you have to do is:

```
#include <string.h>

mem_len = 20
mem_value = 0
ptr = 0x105fc080

memset(ptr. mem_value, mem_len)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use memset function from string.h library.

```
    #include <string.h>

    char *srcadr = 0x105fc080;
    int size = 20;
    memset(srcdr,0,size);
```

Comment: `char *srcadr = 0x105fc080;` isn't valid C so this code won't compile.

Comment: ** Due to  constraint in project, memset is not available

Comment: The answer from unwind seems valid and proper. Absolute addresses are strange anyway, where does the address come from. Also your loop is not changing the value of i.